# Материнка и BootROM

Tags: сеть, железо

Как узнать поддерживает ли конкретная материнка (или бортовая сетевая карта на этой материнке) опцию bootROM?

Comment: Пардон. Забыл уточнить что компа нету)
И доступа к нему нету. Есть название материнки, ну и название сетевой карты.

Comment: ну раз так, имена в студию!)

Comment: Не так важно проверить одну материнку, как важно разобраться в процессе проверки))

ну пример: "Asus N3050I-C" с "Realtek RTL8111H" на борту.

Comment: *важно разобраться в процессе проверки* Процесс элементарен. По модели и ревизии скачиваем мануал у производителя и читаем. Там написано.

Answer (score 0):

В БИОС нужно зайти и в Advanced(Boot Settings Configuration) посмотреть, есть ли такая функция, другие названия:

`LAN Boot ROM`, `LAN option rom`, `Boot ROM Function`